# Understand inline-element, vertical-align, line-box and line-height

Tags: html, css

vertical-align:bottom, means the bottom inline-box matches the bottom of its line-box, so in my case, the  inline-box of span2 is the green one, whose line-height is 100px, inherited from its parent. Its line-box is the black one, also has line-height:100px. so they are bottom aligned.
see pic:
[image]

---

I've already learned that:

1.vertical-align works only for inline/inline-block element

2.vertical-align is based on line-height, not the height of its container!

3.in a line-box, its line-height is the line-height of the inline box(in my opinion, its either inline-element or inline-block element) which has the highest line-height. like pic:

[image]

---

Everything works fine on inline-block element, but it seems that there is a problem with inline-element.

**explanation:**

parent: height:200px, line-height;100px;

div.child:inline-block, vertical-align bottom;

span1: inline, line-height:inherit from parent, which is 100px

span2: inline, line-height:inherit from parent, which is 100px, vertical align: bottom.

To me, the line-box for the code below is like this(you can run the code first):

[image]

**strange behavior for span2 !!! and it becomes even stranger if I set its vertical-align to text-top or text-bottom**

another thing which I found interesting is, if I set display of span to inline block or set the line-height of span to normal (which is 1.16 of its font-size), everything works fine.

can someone explain it? Thanks

```css
div.parent {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  /*key-part*/
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  /*key-part*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: normal;
}

.span1 {
  background-color: white;
   font-size: 50px;
  /*key-part*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.span2 {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 12px;
  /*key-part*/
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">inline-block div</div>
    <span class="span1">Text1</span>
    <span class="span2">Text2</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: One issue that the answer doesn't mention is "set the line-height of span to normal (which is 1.16 of its font-size)", which isn't always true. Most browsers take about 1.2 the font size and then round it to whole pixels, but it depends on the font, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to cover it step by step:

> 1.vertical-align works only for inline/inline-block element

Vertical-align applies to inline-level elements. That's currently: inline, inline-block, inline-table, inline-flex, inline-grid. Vertical-align is also used, but in a different way, for table cells.

> 2.vertical-align is based on line-height, not the height of its container!

Except for table cells, correct.

> 3.in a line-box, its line-height is the line-height of the inline box(in my opinion, its either inline-element or inline-block element) which has the highest line-height.

That's correct for simple cases but not for complex alignment ones. A better approximation goes something like this. Remove all the elements that are vertical-align:top and vertical-align:bottom. Align all the other elements so that their vertical alignment lines are level with one another. Call the box that contains them from the highest top of the aligned elements to the lowest bottom of the aligned elements the proto-line box. The actual height of the line box is then the maximum of the height of the proto-line box and all of the heights of the elements that are aligned top and bottom.

---

Now the relevant part of the specification for your question is this:

> ... for inline non-replaced elements, the box used for alignment is the box whose height is the 'line-height' (containing the box's glyphs and the half-leading on each side, see above). For all other elements, the box used for alignment is the margin box.

So for the span2, the green background area is the box's glyphs and above that are each glyph's upper half-leading, a value which is taken from the 100px line-height inherited from the container block element. It's the top of these half-leadings that aligns with the top of the line-box, not the top of the green background area.

On the other hand, the inline-block div aligns to the bottom of the line box, by the bottom of its bottom margin, and not by any half-leading.

Comment: thanks for your answer, perhaps I need to read something more, right now it's still hard to understand what you said. But thanks you all the same!