# Is this a bug in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This might sound like an outdated topic since no one still uses inline-block property thanks to flex-box and grid but I was wondering about it and I would like to inquire about it.

When creating two divs and assigning them both to display as inline-block and then adding any element inside one of them, the result is quite strange, where the div which contains that element will slide down to the bottom of the other div minus the height of the added element.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

To fix the issue it's only enough to align the div vertically to the top, but what is strange too is that we get the same result even if we align the other div which is not affected without aligning the affected one, so what exactly is happening here?

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background: gray;
}

#left{
     vertical-align: baseline;
}

#right{
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <span>text</span>
</div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

UPDATE:

To clarify things more I removed the child element and added a text outside the two divs, and added two more divs, now all divs are without a flow content, but the first two both of them have a top property while the last two are different, one top and the other is baseline:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}
.right{
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
.left{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
Text
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>

<br>

Text
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

In the first case the Text aligned to the top and in the next aligned to the baseline of the divs even they don't have a flow content.

Comment: try adding max-width and max-height to the textarea textarea {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

Comment: As IE is not dead (yet) `inline-block` still has it's place as `grid` and `flex` are buggy (at best) in even the most recent versions of IE (NOT edge)

Comment: @JonP lol so true.

Comment: this is not a bug, it's vertical alignment which is by default `baseline`

Comment: @TemaniAfif what are you talking about?!!.. you are totally off topic and that question is completely different than this one.

Comment: am not completely off topic, this is exactly the answer you need. The behavior you are having is due to the alignment which is baseline and this explain everything ..  I am adding more duplicates so you can understand this logical behavior

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063197/8620333 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950536/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif is correct. See my answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Since when the parent element inherits its properties from an element within, how come the alignment of the child affect the parent? that's basically my question.

Comment: read the duplicates and you will understand :) that the purpose of closing as duplicate .. I cannot explain within comments this behavior

Comment: now you have a complete list of duplicate, read all of them and everything will be very clear in your mind and you will learn more than you expected ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are also ignoring the fact which I mentioned that you don't need to change the alignment of the element which has inline-block property and to prove it to you I edited my question and this time with alignment to baseline and no problems occur, so explain that now.

Comment: Yes I know you don't need to change the alignment of both element, only one element need vertical-align and it's not the one how contain the text and this is also explained in the duplicate ... you simply need to understand the concept of baseline and containing block (which is described in all the duplicates)

Comment: Both divs are inline-block and both are affected, you are wrong thinking that only the one that conain the text is affected and move down. BOTH divs are aligned to the baseline. Simply take the time to read about this, it's not easy at the start but you will get it

Comment: I started on an answer, but it was locked as a dupe before I was finished, so I posted answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51857106/109392) instead. What I answer there that is not covered by the other answers, is why it behave like it does when one of the boxes is `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: As [Eric Meyer once said](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/) "... knowledge of what goes into the layout of lines of text imparts a sense of astonishment that any page can be successfully displayed in less than the projected age of the universe. "

Comment: As a comment to the statement "This might sound like an outdated topic since no one still uses inline-block property thanks to flex-box and grid" I would say that it is still useful to enable smaller boxes to wrap dynamically by enabling different number of boxes on each line dependent on window width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this happens, is because the default [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value for inline elements is `baseline`.

Then the question becomes: what is the baseline of an `inline-block` element? Here, we have to make a distinction between elements with and without [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content):

- For elements **with** flow content, such as the `left` div in your question, the baseline is the same as the baseline of the last content element.<sup>(*)</sup> For the `left` div, this corresponds to the baseline of the inner `span`.
  <sub>(*) There are some additional considerations when setting the element's overflow, but I'll leave that out of scope.</sub>
- For elements **without** flow content, such as the `right` div in your question, the baseline is the bottom of the element's margin box. For the `right` div, this corresponds to the bottom of the div itself.

So, to summarize: the reason you're seeing a vertical shift is because the elements are vertically aligned according to their baseline, and the baselines for elements with and without content are calculated differently.

To test this out, just try adding some text to the `right` div, and you'll see how both baselines are now the same.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Text</div>
<div id="right">Other text</div>
```

By animating the font size, the example below demonstrates even more clearly how changes in the baseline affect vertical positioning:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

#left {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  animation: anim 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {font-size: 100%;}
  100% {font-size: 300%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Text</div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Comment: to make it more tricky and also clear I would add text to the next div with a bigger font-size so we can clearly see the baseline ;) probably an animation that increase decrease the font-size

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for your feedback. I've added the animation :)

Comment: That explains the initial state when both divs are on the baseline. I'm not convinced that it answers the OP's question, which is why does setting *either* div to `vertical-align:top` remove the offset.

Comment: Exactly and that's the core question, I don't need an explanation that setting the vertical alignment to top will move the element from baseline to the top, I already mentioned that in my text but the real question remains  why the second dev affect the baseline of the body which is the actual parent for both divs and for more clarity see my last update.

Comment: @Tarek.hms read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align ... you need to first understand how the baseline of the parent element is caclulated (because this is what is used for the baseline value) and you need to also understand how the line box of an element is calculated (because top consider this) ... then you will understand how each element is aligned ... The duplicate questions contains link to specfication that explain all this, you simply need to take the time understanding them. All your examples are almost the same even you last edit.

Comment: And am pretty sure @Alohci will agree with me since he wrote one of those answers and he knows better than me those stuffs ... even if you reopen the quesiton, you will simply get the same answers already provided. All the example you made deal with the same thing: What is baseline?, how its caclulated? what is a line box? how vertical-align:top behave? how vertical-align:baseline behave? why adding text change things? etc .. all these answers are in the duplicate

Comment: @Tarek.hms and here is the relevant part of the documentation : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Well actually, I think a full answer to the question, especially in its latest form, requires an explanation of how the line box is constructed. That the items not aligned to the top and bottom line box edges are aligned with each other first, and then the top and bottom items added. I'm not sure any of the duplicates actually does that. I don't have time at present to write a proper answer though.

Comment: @Alohci you already did it here if I am not wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305825/understand-inline-elemnt-vertical-align-line-box-and-line-height

Comment: Well, I have actually written an answer that covers this, but the question was lacked as dupe before I was finished, so I posted it [on this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51857106/109392) instead.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - so I did. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I admit it, I was wrong, it makes me feel like I'm learning CSS all over again, I used to believe that CSS is much simpler but now I see the principle logic behind all this, thank you guys for these explanations and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Tarek.hms Don't feel too bad about it. The logic behind vertical-align is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The display: inline-block Value

Compared to display: inline, the major difference is that display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.

Also, with display: inline-block, **the top and bottom margins/paddings are respected**, but with display: inline they are not.

Compared to display: block, the major difference is that display: inline-block does not add a line-break after the element, so the element can sit next to other elements.

and

excuse me textarea is inline-block, but what line is correct,
the browser think **the bottom of second inline-block is position of line** so 
when he go to draw children he see the textarea must be inline and change position of it to **the bottom of second inline-block is position of line** and because it is any padding and it position are relative it cause to parent div move to bottom just for textarea be inline

Comment: i found it please check :) - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html